# Email marked as spam if it contains specific email address

Tags: email, spam

We have an email address that causes us quite some headache. Sending an email from this account (via webmail) causes the message to randomly end up in the recipient's spam box (unfortunetely this is not constant).
But that's not the worse thing... Emails sent from other accounts (and different domanins) are also marked as spam and/or dangerous if they have the above email address written inside the body text.
We checked with MxToolbox's blacklist function, but the domain doesn't appear to be blacklisted. Tests emails were sent to Google and Outlook recipients, both yielding with the same result. 
Can somebdy shine a light on this problem?
Tnx

Comment: Who are the recipients ? Internal domain addresses or external ones ?

Comment: Please repeat the test with a plain-text (no html part) email and without the @ sign. I suspect the fact that it is a mail address is unimportant here, the words contained in the address or the way your mail client generates markup might be the issue.

Comment: @anx just tried sending a plain text email with just the domain name (beside some dummy-text), email ended up in spam folder...